# How to use Javascript to dynamically change the background of a list of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, colors

I have an html list that looks as follows:

```
<nav id="PageNav">
    <div id="TimeContainer">
        <ul id="TimeList">
            <li>
                <button id="welcome_button" onclick="setWelcome()">
                    <span>Home<span></span>
                </button>
            </li>

            <li>
                <button id="resume_button" onclick="setResume()">
                    <span>Resume<span>
                </button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="static/scripts/page_change.js"></script>

</nav>
```

When a user clicks a button I need to call a script and set the background of each of these elements to a different color. I am trying to do it as follows:

```
function setResume() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("MainText").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;

      document.getElementById("resume_button").style.backgroundColor =
        "rgba(25, 129, 190, 0.7)";

      var button_list = document.getElementById("TimeList").getElementsByTagName("li").innerHTML;

      for(element in button_list){
        element.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "static/resume.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

However this does nothing, not even console errors.

Comment: Are you testing this code by making a request to it over HTTP? In other words, do you have this file on a web server and are you calling it with an HTTP request? AJAX only works over a web server.

Comment: I am running it on a flask server, locally on python

Comment: Do you see the XHR request getting made when the dev. tools are opened to the Network tab? And do you see a 200 response code?

Comment: Yes. the server itslef runs and many js functions are currently called. it is this specific one that does not work.

Comment: That's not really what I asked. Do you see a network request for `static/resume.txt` and is it coming back as 200? If so, click on the file name and check the response itself to confirm that the correct `responseText` is being delivered.

Comment: The response code is 200 for static/resume.txt

This is not a server problem, it's a js syntax problem. i.e it's an error within the lines that are trying to change the color of the element

Comment: Well, you said you weren't getting any errors. Please change the color from the RGB to a test color of `yellow` and see if that works. Setting RGB colors via JavaScript can be problematic.

Comment: I said the console wasn't reporting any errors. Which it isn't.

Comment: check what is the value of readystate you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The way I was trying to solve this is wrong. this seems to be the correct way to do it:

```
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = " rgba(0,0,0,0.6)";
  }
```

Comment: A better approach would be to set up a CSS class like this: `.resultColor { background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6); }` and then when you need to apply that color, you'd write: `document.getElementById("resume_button").classList.add(resultColor);`.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I was just trying to get stuff working first.

Comment: I understand, but when setting RGB values via JavaScript as strings that should be set, you get the problem you are experiencing - that is the issue - the way you wrote the string didn't have spaces exactly as needed. Using `.classList` avoids inline styles (which you should always try to do anyway) and the static setting of the color as a string.

Comment: I see, didn;t know that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Setting RGB/RGBA values as strings via JavaScript can be problematic because some systems get extremely picky as to where the spaces are in the string and this is the problem you are experiencing.

```
"rgba(0,0,0,.5)"     // Usually won't work
"rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)"  // Usually will but may require a leading space as well
```

Now, as a general rule, you should avoid setting inline styles in the first place as they are harder to read/debug and more importantly, they lead to duplicated code and are hard to override. Instead, a solution that kills two birds with one stone is to set up a CSS class ahead of time and simply add/remove that class via JavaScript as needed using [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
function setResume() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("MainText").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;

      // Just apply the appropriate, already declared class
      document.getElementById("resume_button").classList.add("responseStyle");

      var button_list = document.getElementById("TimeList").getElementsByTagName("li").innerHTML;

      for(element in button_list){
        // Again, add/remove classes rather than configuring inline styles with strings:
        element.classList.add("black");
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "static/resume.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```css
.responseStyle { background-color:rgba(25, 129, 190, 0.7); }
.buttonListStyle { background-color:black; }
```

```html
<nav id="PageNav">
    <div id="TimeContainer">
        <ul id="TimeList">
            <li>
                <button id="welcome_button" onclick="setWelcome()">
                    <span>Home<span></span>
                </button>
            </li>

            <li>
                <button id="resume_button" onclick="setResume()">
                    <span>Resume<span>
                </button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="static/scripts/page_change.js"></script>

</nav>
```

**NOTES:**

1) This line:

```
var button_list = document.getElementById("TimeList").getElementsByTagName("li").innerHTML;
```

has a few issues. First, `getElementsByTagName()` returns a node list, so it won't have an `.innerHTML` property in the first place, only elements will. And, even if it did have `.innerHTML`, that would return a string, so attempting to loop over `button_list` with a `for/in` loop wouldn't actually loop over any HTML elements, it would loop over the characters in that string.

Here's how you should do this:

```js
document.getElementById("yourWay").addEventListener("click", yourWay);
document.getElementById("correctWay").addEventListener("click", correctWay);

function yourWay() {
  var button_list = document.getElementById("TimeList").getElementsByTagName("li").innerHTML;

  // This attempts to loop over the string returned by .innerHTML, not the child elements and
  // because you are using a for/in loop, nothing happens because for/in is for looping over objects.
  for(element in button_list){
     element.style.backgroundColor = "black";
     console.log(element);
  }
}


function correctWay() {
  // .getElementsByTagName() returns a "live" node list and has performance implications.
  // Instead, use .querySelectorAll() for better performance.
  
  // If we want to use the .forEach method of an Array, we have to convert the node list
  // returned by .querySelectorAll() to an array for best browser compatibility.
  var button_list = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("TimeList").querySelectorAll("li"));

  button_list.forEach(function(el){
     el.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  });
}
```

```html
<nav id="PageNav">
    <div id="TimeContainer">
        <ul id="TimeList">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Resume</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<input type="button" id="yourWay" value="Your Way">
<input type="button" id="correctWay" value="Correct Way">
```

2) The `for/in` loop in JavaScript is mean to iterate an object's properties (which would include its inherited properties as well as its "own" properties). To enumerate an array or array-like object, use a counting loop or `.forEach()`.